# Interpolation of permutation polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, polynomials, field-theory, finite-fields

Consider the finite field $\mathbb F_q$ where $q=2^n$ and $n \to \infty$. Now given $t = O(1)$ and $x_1,\ldots,x_t,y_1,\ldots,y_t$ where $\forall i \ne j,x_i \ne x_j,y_i \ne y_j$, do one has a [permutation polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_polynomial) $f \in \mathbb F_q[x]$ such that $\mathrm{deg}(f)=O_t(1)$ and  $\forall i,f(x_i) = y_i$?

There exist related [results](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/C7A52DC91FC1A69AB7108B08E3C094E2/S0004972714000173a.pdf/a-note-on-interpolation-of-permutations-of-a-subset-of-a-finite-field.pdf) but measuring the complexity of $f$ in terms of linear combinations of $x^{q-2}$ instead of the degree.